# outputting feed urls in template in Django 1.4

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.4

Prior to moving up to Django 1.4, I had a feed_dict defined in URLs. A context processor picked it up, so then in the template I could loop through it and output all my defined feed URLs.

With the changes in how Django 1.4 handles feed URLs, how can I do this again?